# Move to a specific tab index when leaving another input with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, outsystems

I have a page that is generated dynamically and all the tabindex's are preset.  What I am attempting to do is to have the focus set to a specific tabindex when another input loses focus.  For example if I have `<input tabindex=119>` and another with `<input tabindex=16>` how can I get to tabindex=16 when 119 loses focus?  I have tried

```
$(zip).keydown(function(event) {
            if (event.which == 9) {
                event.preventDefault();
                //$('#DublinTheme_wt213_block_wtMainContent_WebPatterns_wt50_block_wtPanelContent_WebPatterns_wt191_block_wtColumn1_wtVendors_EmailAddress').focus();
                $('input').find("[tabindex=16]").focus();
            }
        });
```

where zip is the input field id of tabindex = 119.  This did nothing at all for me.  I have also tried just setting the focus to the id of the input I want:
`$('#DublinTheme_wt213_block_wtMainContent_WebPatterns_wt50_block_wtPanelContent_WebPatterns_wt191_block_wtColumn1_wtVendors_EmailAddress').focus();` 
put in the place of `$('input').find("[tabindex=16]").focus();` 
again, this did not place the focus on the correct input.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `$("input[tabindex=16]").focus();' or `$('[tabindex=16]').focus();` ?

Comment: @Triby I just did and that did not set the focus either.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't put Outsystems generated id's hardcoded in your script. Create a new expression like in the example below. The blur event will be executed when an element loses focus.

Obviously replace the `yourOutsystemsTabIndex199Element` and `yourOutsystemsTabIndex16Element` with the name of your inputs.

Also set the expression so it doesn't escape content.

```
"<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#" + yourOutsystemsTabIndex199Element.id + "').on('blur', function(){
    $('#" + yourOutsystemsTabIndex16Element.id + "').focus();
  });
});
</script>"
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Mark, should I be putting this in the javascript section for the block, or on the in the extended properties for the input?  Thanks

Comment: @Jim Neither of both, use it in an expression. It may sound a bit ugly but this way you can use id selectors to target the exact element that you want without hard coding the generated id's. The id's can change when you ever decide to move your elements.

Comment: @Jim Added a screenshot to clarify. You can see this working at https://mark-baijens.outsystemscloud.com/test/Home.aspx (as long my personal space doesn't fall asleep)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the image, that helped a lot.  I did what you recommended, but I have an error in my expression that states `'Text' data type required instead of 'None'` I don't see where to fix this, can you help?  Thanks!!

Comment: is this because my second field is a type of email?

Comment: The email type shouldn't matter. Did you put dubbele quotes around your expression? Can you post the expression that you have?

Comment: "<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#" + VendorForm.Record.Vendor.RemitZip + "').on('blur', function(){
    $('#" + VendorForm.Record.Vendor.EmailAddress + "').focus();
  });
});
</script>"

Comment: It looks like you are using the record parameters in the expression. You need to name your input elements and  use that name to retrieve the ID of the input element like: "namedInput.id"

Comment: So if the name of the zip field is Vendors_Zip2 I use that and not the RemitZip that I put?  When I did that I got the text data required instead of none error.

Comment: Yeah then you use Vendor_Zip2.Id

Comment: Error went away when I added the .Id.  I will test now and let you know the outcome.  Thanks for all the help so far!!